# Ruby on Rails table relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a `product` table where it list down all the products user created. In product table there is `country` which indicate the product origin. Now to make the product country visible, the user table must have `merchant status` of 1.

Following code is use to pull the countries from product table:

```
@countries = Product.select(:country).distinct.where("country is not null and country <> ''").pluck(:country)
```

Product Model:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
end
```

User Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :products
end
```

How can I modified the above code, so it will include `merchant_status` in user table? Means I need list down countries only if `merchant_status = 1` in User table. Thanks!!

Comment: you can try this  `Product.joins(:user).where("country is not null and country <> ''").where(:users => {: merchant_status => 1}).pluck(:country)`

Comment: @VishalJAIN thanks!! it's work fine

Comment: @VishalJAIN Please post it as answer, and let the OP accept it.

Comment: @VishalJAIN, yes you can post it as answer. BTW, there is one similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36277044/rails-get-unique-country-with-cities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this way:

```
Product.joins(:user).where("country is not null and country <> ''").where(:users => {:merchant_status => 1}).pluck(:country)
```