# Rails get unique country with cities

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

How can I list unique country followed by related cities? Following were my product table:

```
name  country   city
p1     US        New York
p2     US        Boston
p3     US        Chicago
k1     UK        London
k2     UK        Liverpool
```

Controller:

```
@countries = Product.joins(:user).distinct.where("country is not null and country <> ''").where(:users => {:merchant_status => 1}).pluck(:country)

@cities = Product.joins(:user).distinct.where("city is not null and city <> ''").where(:users => {:merchant_status => 1}).pluck(:city)

@countries.map! {|country| country.split.map(&:capitalize).join(' ')}

@search_location_country = @countries
```

And in my View:

```
<ul id="color-dropdown-menu" class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">

  <% @search_location_country.each do |country| %>
    <li class="input"><a href="#"><%= country %></a></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

How can I sort the end result for drop down like this:

```
US
 - New York
 - Boston
 - Chicago
UK
 - London
 - Liverpool
```

Thanks!!

EDIT

To be display something like this:

[image]

Comment: What is `@cities` for?

Comment: @sschmeck cities i used for search without dropdown. All the country and city search work fine, but i need to sort out the way it displayed. Country followed by lists of Cities

Comment: you are looking for select2 element or similar I tink

Comment: @Guru, it's like, get the unique country followed by list of cities belong to that country

Comment: then try with group_by ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey you can try this way using `group` it gives you all distinct records

```
@countries_cities = Product.joins(:user).where("country is not null and country <> ''").where("city is not null and city <> ''").where(:users => {:merchant_status => 1}).group(:country, :city).select("country,city").as_json
```

It will give you output like

```
[{:country => "US", :city => "New York"}..]
```

If you want to again group it by country then used like

```
cchs = @countries_cities.group_by{|cc| cc["country"]}
```

Convert above multidimensional array to hash using

```
@country_cities_hash =  = Hash[*cchs]
```

In your view file as

```
<% @country_cities_hash.each do |country, cities| %>
  <li class="input"><a href="#"><%= country %></a></li>
 <%  cities.each do |city| %>
  <li class="input"><a href="#"><%= "#{city}(#{country})" %></a></li>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: How can I modified the view to display country > city?

Comment: `["Malaysia", [{"id"=>nil, "country"=>"Malaysia", "city"=>"Kuching"}, {"id"=>nil, "country"=>"Malaysia", "city"=>"Kota Kinabalu"}, {"id"=>nil, "country"=>"Malaysia", "city"=>"Kuala Lumpur"}, {"id"=>nil, "country"=>"Malaysia", "city"=>"Shah Alam"}, {"id"=>nil, "country"=>"Malaysia", "city"=>"Langkawi"}]]`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I do understand the question but... I guess you have a collection of Product, looking like this :

```
produts = [
  <Product @name="p1", @country="US" @city="New York">,
  <Product @name="p1", @country="US" @city="Boston">,
  <Product @name="k2", @country="FR" @city="Paris">,
  ...
]
```

In that case, to index the city names by country :

```
@cities_by_coutry = products.inject({}) do |index, product|
  index[product.country] ||= []
  index[product.country] << product.city
  index
end
```

Which result to :

```
{"US"=>["New York", "Boston"], "FR"=>["Paris"]}
```

Then you can iterate :

```
@cities_by_coutry.each do |country, cities|
  cities.each do |city|
    puts "City: #{city} is in country {country}"
  end
end
```